# Product of Abelian varieties with complex multiplication

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties

We take Abelian varieties $A_1, A_2,\dotsc,A_n$ over a number field.
If $A_1, A_2,\dotsc,A_n$ have complex multiplication, then does the product $A_1\times A_2 \times \dotsb \times A_n$ have complex multiplication?
Conversely, if the product $A_1\times A_2 \times \dotsb \times A_n$ has complex multiplication, then how about $A_i$?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your definition of complex multiplication. With Shimura's definition, products of abelian varieties with complex multiplication need not have complex multiplication. With the most common current definition — an abelian variety has complex multiplication if its Mumford–Tate group is a torus — both answers are Yes. Proof: $\operatorname{MT}(A\times B)\subset \operatorname{MT}(A)\times \operatorname{MT}(B)$ and projects onto both factors.

Your definition is only correct for simple abelian varieties. See these notes: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/cm.html

Comment: Thank you very much. My definition of complex multiplication is the following: for an Abelian variety $A$ over a number field $L$, we say $A$ has complex multiplication if there is a CM filed $K$ such that there is an isomorphism $\mathtext{End}_L(A)\simeq K$. 
This definition is compatible with the most common definition?

Comment: @OOOOOO by rigidity of abelian varities, if $A_1\not =A_2$, $End(A_1\times A_2)=End(A_1)\times End(A_2)$ so as this answer said,only the endomorphism of a simple abelian variety can be a field, must peaple define complex multiplication Like you but they use a CM-algebra instead of a CM field, in that case what you want is true